# Facebook API PHP: Emojis not showing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a simple tool that generates some custom HTML based on data from the website.
After, we can simply publish this content to a Facebook page via the Facebook SDK (API).

The following PHP code is an excerpt of how the $content is set up:

```
$content = '';
$content .= '&#128205; The address<br>';
$content .= '&#128704; 2 bathrooms<br>';
```

Via some AJAX code, this $content is shown as HTML in a div on the page, where the user can further edit the texts.

Then, the user can click on 'share' and via AJAX the post is published to Facebook. I use the following PHP code to format the content before it is passed to the FB API:

```
$content = str_replace('<br>',chr(10),$content);
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
$content = strip_tags($content);
```

The problem is that the emojis are not showing on Facebook. When I test it with

```
$content = html_entity_decode('&#65039;');
```

Then the emoji is showing correctly, but it seems that it's not working because I get $content via AJAX/Jquery with

```
var content = $('#content').html();
```

And then pass it through AJAX.

So I suppose there is a formatting issue, but I can't wait a way to fix it..

EDIT: because the content is first shown on the page in a div, the emojis are turned into `<img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/14.0.0/svg/1f4cd.svg">`

After, my Jquery/AJAX code takes the contents of this div, so I assume it takes the above  instead of the `'&#128205;'`. But how can I work around this?

EDIT 2:

Passing

```
$content = '';
$content .= '&#128205; The address<br>';
$content .= '&#128704; 2 bathrooms<br>';
```

Directly to the Facebook API works and shows the emojis.

First using an other PHP function that adds the above code to a div via JQUERY/AJAX, and then getting the div's content using $('#content').html() and passing this does not work.

Comment: _"because the content is first shown on the page in a div, the emojis are turned into [...]"_ - that must be something in your system explicitly doing this then. HTML itself has no built-in "magic" that would replace a character with an image all by itself.

Comment: (Removed the `facebook` tag, because your actual problem appears to have absolutely nothing to do specifically with Facebook.)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with jQuery, but contains mostly PHP code? Is this really a jQuery or AJAX problem? What did you try to resolve it? Does the AJAX call return the data as expected?

Comment: I have edited my code (EDIT 2) to further clarify what I mean. I believe I need to encode/decode my `var content = $('#content').html();` in some way.

Comment: Still, what do you mean by "does not work"? Did you check whether PHP returns the data as expected or not?

Comment: Hi Nico, when I log the ajax response in the console, I can see the data is returned correctly, with all emojis shown as `&#128205;`. It seems that after adding this response to the div with `$('#content').html(response)`, that these emojies are turned into an image. Perhaps good to mention: I'm running my code in the WordPress admin, so this may be the reason why they are 'magically' turned into images.

Comment: I think the Jquery .html() is also part of the problem. I'm going to do some tests with .text() to try to prevent the formatting of emojis in the div.

Comment: Hi Nico, I found a solution (see my answer). Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution.

As I suspected, the problem was with Jquery's `element.HTML()`, which seems to format the data in some way.

I have now added a hidden input field, where I add and get the data via `element.val()` instead of `element.html()`;

Also, to prevent the auto-formatting (perhaps caused by WordPress) of emojis into images, I have created some custom tags like `{sun}`, which are only replaced with their HTML codes (like `&#65039;`) just before posting to Facebook.